# ngRepeat Add to the current index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code, I want to add 1 to the current index of the second Name, because if I don't, it will output the same name in a single line.  How do I add to the current index of ngRepeat?

```
<ul id="speakerlist" ng-repeat="data in result">
    <li>
        <div class="col">
            <h3>{{data.Name}}</h3>
        </div >
        <div class="col">
            <h3>{{data.Name | $index+1}}</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I solved this by using jQuery, but I want to do it in angularjs way.

**EDIT: additional info**

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[])
app.controller("myController",function($scope){
  $scope.result=[{"Name":"Michael Jordan"},{"Name":"Kobe Bryant"},{"Name":"Kevin Durant"},{"Name":"Stephen Curry"} ];
  });
```

The result I want Is:

```
Michael Jordan Kobe Bryant
Kevin Durant Stephen Curry
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to display a `li` for every two items. You can do it something like this:

```
<ul id="speakerlist" ng-repeat="data in result">
    <li ng-if="$even">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>{{result[$index].Name}}</h3>
        </div >
        <div class="col">
            <h3>{{result[$index + 1].Name}}</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Of course you would also have to include some kind of check if the `$index` can reach the last one (if the collection has an un-even amount of items)

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ox611hya/1/)

---

You could even remove the double col html if you don't like duplicate html code:

```
<ul id="speakerlist" ng-repeat="data in result">
    <li ng-if="$even">
        <div class="col"
             ng-repeat="item in [result[$index], result[$index + 1]]">
            <h3>{{item.Name}}</h3>
        </div >
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Then it will show only one `li`, because it starts with `$index = 0`, where the `ng-if` resolves to true.

Comment: Sorry. tell me what happened, if  the result length is only one?

Comment: @RameshRajendran see added jsfiddle, it will work fine. Also I mentioned that OP should check of course for un-even amounts like one

Comment: indeed this only shown one li, butthe result is almost there, i'll try to work around on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code `<h3>{{data.Name }} {{$index+1}}</h3>` instead of your code

`<h3>{{data.Name | $index+1}}</h3>`

*The result format looks like*

```
Ramesh 
Ramesh1
Rajendran
Rajendran1
```

Comment: I'll try this one out when I get back to my laptop.. thanks

Comment: unfotunately, this just output the current index + 1, but doesn't took the name on the next index

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it simple this way.

```js
var app=angular.module("myApp",[])
app.controller("myController",function($scope){
  $scope.result=[{"Name":"hari"},{"Name":"ram"} ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <ul id="speakerlist" ng-repeat="data in result track by $index">
    <li>
        <div class="col">
            <h3 >{{data.Name}} {{data.Name+1 }}</h3>
        </div >
        
    </li>
</ul>
  </body>
```

">

Comment: I don't want the output to be that way.  I'm expectecting it to be, hari ram in a single bullet

Comment: then it's just data[0].name and data[1].name.

Comment: so if i have a hundred index, how do I increment that 0, 1

Comment: I still don't get what end result you mean..could you give a sample json of input and required output ?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do this ?

```
<ul id="speakerlist" >
    <li ng-repeat="data in result">
        <div class="col">
            <h3>{{data.Name}}</h3>
        </div >
    </li>
</ul>
```

This way you don't need to change de $index, it will be automatic

Comment: Because apparently he wants to display 2 names besides each other, in one `li`

Comment: because I have to display 2 names in single list.

Comment: The question was not really clear about that, next time, please be more explicit.